# IBM Watson Speech to Text Audio/Basic not accepting narrowband .WAV

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I have written a program in Python 3.6 that makes use of IBM Watson's Speech to Text library. When the program searches a folder and reads through each `.wav` file individually, it's supposed to check the file's frequency and flag my IBM Watson integration differently. Then, it takes the response and maps it to a list. Through stub testing, the main, problematic code in question is here:

```
        speech_to_text.set_detailed_response(True)

        # Narrowband
        if rate < 16000:
            x = json.loads(
                json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/basic', timestamps=True, max_alternatives=0).get_result(),
                indent=2), object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
                )

        # Broadband
        else:
            x = json.loads(
                json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/wav', timestamps=True, max_alternatives=0).get_result(),
                indent=2), object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
                )
```

This program is completely functional when I supply it with a file over 16 kbps. However, anything less than that, and I get this error:

```
  File "echo_cli.py", line 64, in <module>
    json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/basic', timestamps=True, max_alternatives=0).get_result(),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\speech_to_text_v1.py", line 373, in recognize
    accept_json=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\watson_service.py", line 479, in request
    info=error_info, httpResponse=response)
watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: This 8000hz audio input requires a narrow band model.  See https://<STT_API_ENDPOINT>/v1/models for a list of available models., Code: 400 , Information: {'code_description': 'Bad Request'} , X-dp-watson-tran-id: stream01-167902601 , X-global-transaction-id: f257b1145ba417780a01fd89
```

As a note, the files I'm using are over a network drive. However, I get the same error when I copy them to my local drive, so I'm thinking that this is an unrelated issue. I'm including this text just in case it rings any bells I'm unaware of.

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/python.html?python#websocket_methods) documentation, I should be able to accept a narrowband file with `audio/basic`, and according to print commands I've used, when I load a narrowband `.wav`, my program is executing the correct code. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only pass the `audio/basic` MIME type if that's the type of the file you're uploading (also known as a "Sun .au" file, it's one of the [oldest audio file types out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format)). If you're uploading a WAV file, specify the MIME type as `audio/wav`, no matter what the sample rate.

Comment: this answer is spot on, WAVE files have a header containing the sampling rate, length, etc if you pass `audio/wav` the service will get the encoding info from the header. If you pass `audio/basic` you are requesting the file to be processed as if it were a leaderless raw file. It might work for a Broadband WAVE file since it will treat the header as audio bytes, but since the header is short this is not a big deal.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However, I attempted a fix by removing the option to send data through audio/basic, routing everything through audio/wav, and I got the same error.

Comment: @EthanHill you also have to specify a narrowband model, like the error says.